# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function how can i use async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i want to use async await in middleware

but when i use my code this error occure

const refrsh = await User.findOne({
^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

how can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
            exports.authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
              const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
              const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
              if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
              jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                  const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken;
                  const refrsh = await User.findOne({
                where: {id:req.body.kakaoid}
                  })
                }
              
                req.user = user;
                next();
              });
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the `(err, user)` callback an `async` function. It should work out alright in this particular case:

```
exports.authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, async (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken;
      const refrsh = await User.findOne({
        where: { id: req.body.kakaoid },
      });
    }

    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` keyword before anonymous callback `(err, user)` function.

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, async (err, user) => {
  // your code...
  const refrsh = await User.findOne({
    where: {id:req.body.kakaoid}
  });
 // your code...
});
```

Comment: That's not the right function to make `async`.

Comment: updated the code, ignored the inner function.

Comment: The outer function does not need to be `async` since it doesn't do anything async.

Comment: function which is enclosing the await code will be async.

Comment: The outer function doesn't need to be `async` since it only uses callback-based asynchronicity.

Comment: outer function is not async. only (err, user) callback is async.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `async` when decalre function that you want `await`:

```
 jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, async (err, user) => { ...
```